# GAE alternative for business web application

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications, bigdata, paas

I'm interested in building a web application. I like the Google App Engine, datastore and bigquery. Google offers a lot of useful tools.

But I'm not sure, that Google is the right decision for a web based business application. What if the costumer didn't trust Google and want to run the application in his own private cloud? Is it possible to migrate the application and datastore? Is there a better choice for those applications, which is as powerful as Google and also easy to use? Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a programming question, but you could look at [AppScale](http://www.appscale.com/) and [CapeDwarf](http://capedwarf.org/)

But, whilst they may give you something similar to App Engine from a programmer's perspective, you need to consider the scale of the underlying infrastructure too.